# Dynamically initialize window in ZK

Tags: java, window, initialization, zk

Is it possible to initialize a window that I've already put in a page with a .zul spicified dynamically?

I do like this:

```
<n:div id = "content">  
     <window id="content_wnd">
     </window>
</n:div>
```

- it is at the main window

and i want, for example initialize this "content_wnd" window by "/login_wnd.zul":

```
content_wnd = (Window)Executions.createComponents(
                "/login_wnd.zul", null, null);
```

and after it executes, a new window appears in the bottom of the page, not in the

```
<n:div>
</n:div>
```

block, where the "content_wnd" is placed.
What's wrong here and what is the correct way to dynamically put a window into a specified place of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected behavior. Because the java reference `content_wnd` is not the child of `<div id="content">` but the objecct `content_wnd` it refered to before you called `Executions.createComponents`.
To append the window as a child of the `content` do the following.
*.zul

```
<n:div id = "content"/>
```

create `Window` in java with content div as [parent](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Executions.html#createComponents%28org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.PageDefinition,%20org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component,%20java.util.Map%29)

```
content_wnd = (Window)Executions.createComponents(
                "/login_wnd.zul", content, null);
```

where `content` is a referenc to the div.
For example add the field

```
@Wire
Div content;
```